# Android studio how force all devices to download the new release from play store

Tags: android, google-play

Hy,

I m published a software on the store and later i did some update , but i noticed that most times , the phone which has downloaded the previous version of my software doesn't update automatically the new release that i 've published till they go directly on the store on the page of the application and see ( Update) .

Is there any configuration to do so that when i publish a new release of the software , all devices automatically download the new version like on Facebook when there is a new release.

Comment: you can use firebase remote config

Answer (score 0):

it is not good practice to auto-download/update app for user. But still if you wish, you can use [In-app updates where you can verify/check and update app from your app itself](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates). Or else you can take help from your backend/API developers of your app, to force auto-update. That is, you can show dialog to update your app if users are using older version and that flag will be provided from backend side.